# Pygame simple bouncing animation

Tags: python, animation, pygame, geometry

I have this program from a pygame tutorial:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 320, 240
speed = [2, 2]
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit();
        ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
        if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]
        if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
            speed[1] = -speed[1] 

        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

It is a simple bouncing ball. What I want is to replace the ball (ball.gif) with a circle which will be drawn using pygame without making big changes to the code. I mean, the only thing I want to change is the ball by replacing it with a circle and animate that circle with the same code I used to animate the ball. Is there any way I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I was having trouble figuring this out but, I finally did it.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window_w = 800
window_h = 600

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

FPS = 120

window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_w, window_h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game: ")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def game_loop():

    block_size = 20

    velocity = [1, 1]

    pos_x = window_w/2
    pos_y = window_h/2

    running = True

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pos_x += velocity[0]
        pos_y += velocity[1]

        if pos_x + block_size > window_w or pos_x < 0:
            velocity[0] = -velocity[0]

        if pos_y + block_size > window_h or pos_y < 0:
            velocity[1] = -velocity[1]

        # DRAW
        window.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, black, [pos_x, pos_y, block_size, block_size])
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


game_loop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to replace

```
screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
```

with

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, ballrect.center, radius)
```

[Pygame's draw module](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) allows for other shapes to be drawn as well.  In the code above, you may fill in `color` and `radius` with your desired values.  `color` is a tuple with three integers in the range 0-255.

Comment: But if I do that, it means that it uses the rectangular area of the image. And, for example, if the circle diameter is smaller or bigger than the length of the rectangle "ballrect", the circle will not bounce exactly when it hits the margins of the screen. In order to do that, I will have to use an image the same size of the circle... Is there a way that I can use only the circle without having to use an image?

Comment: If you draw with pygame.draw, then yes, your rect size needs to match the size of the circle if you want to use the rect for collisions.  But no, you do not still need an image.  To remove the need for the rect, you'd need to re-write the collision detection to check for things like circle-plane intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.
Download the image [from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6ToU.png)

```py
import pygame
import sys

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600,600
ROWS, COLS = 8,8
SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH//COLS
WIDTH, HEIGHT = SQUARE_SIZE*COLS, SQUARE_SIZE*ROWS
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

class Ball:
    GRAVITY = 0.5
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.target_x = (SQUARE_SIZE*col)+SQUARE_SIZE/2
        self.target_y = (SQUARE_SIZE*row)+SQUARE_SIZE/2
        self.x = self.target_x
        self.y = 0
        self.vel = 10
        self.img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("ball2.png"), (SQUARE_SIZE-20, SQUARE_SIZE-20))
        self.landed = False

    def draw(self):
        self.update()
        pygame.draw.circle(WIN, (0,255,0), (self.x, self.y), 15)
    
    def update(self):
        if not self.landed:
            self.vel += self.GRAVITY
            self.y += self.vel
            if self.y > self.target_y:
                self.vel = -(self.vel*0.70)
                if (abs(self.vel)<1):
                    self.landed = True
                self.y += self.vel


def draw_board(ball_list):
    WIN.fill((0,0,0))
    for row in range(ROWS):
        for col in range(row%2, COLS, 2):
            pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (255,0,0), (row*SQUARE_SIZE, col*SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))

def create_balls(ball_list):
    x = []
    for row in range(ROWS):
        for col in range(COLS):
            if ball_list[row][col] ==1: x.append(Ball(row, col))
    return x
    
def main():
    ball_list = [
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
        [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    ]
    balls = create_balls(ball_list)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


        draw_board(ball_list)
        for ball in balls:
            ball.draw()
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(60)

main()
```